# Batch copy command doesn't reach subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch command to copy and move file with a new name to another directory.  When I added one more level of subfolder it does not copy but when I remove the added subfolder and move the file to the previous level it does copy.  Here is it is:

```
cd /d dir "U:\Sourcing\Vendor Demand Planning\Customer CPFR\BBM\"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /o:-d "BBM Tool *.xlsx"') do (
    copy "%%I" "..\Pricing Project\BBM Tool.xlsx"
    exit /b
)
```

If I removed the BBM level and move the file into the Customer CPFR level it works.  I edited this batch from another one that had the target file in the CPFR folder.  The file I need to copy is in the BBM folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the "Pricing Project" directory is on the same level as "Customer CPFR" hence the target of the `copy` should be "..\..\Pricing Project...

---

(later edit)

Also `dir` in the `CD` line should be removed.

Comment: Yes it is on the same level.  Are you saying the number of dots before \Pricing Project determines folder level or am I missing your explaination.  I did try with the dots but it didn't work.

Comment: AAAck!  Looks like a markdown glitch. The copy should be two dots-backslash-two-dots-backslash-Pricing Project. It seems to be rendered as four dots. I'll try editing the response....(later) Edit successful...

Comment: I have ..\..\Pricing Project\Newfilename  Didn't work.  It picks up the file but just couldn't put into the target folder.

Comment: What was the error message? It's safe to add a `pause` command before the `exit /b` if that helps... If you have `copy "%%I" "..\..\Pricing Project\Newfilename"` then that should work. Very puzzling. Perhaps try `ECHO copy "%%I" "..\Pricing Project\BBM Tool.xlsx"` to see whether there's anything amiss...

Comment: The Pause command before exit /b didn't work but when I put it before the for /f command, I get "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect" error message

Comment: `cd /d dir ` should be `cd /d ` . Since you weren't changing to the `U:\...` directory, the current directory would be used to find `"BBM Tool *.xlsx".

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Do you want to edit your response to include edits or do you just want me to accept the last edit as the answer.  Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change COPY to XCOPY and use /S

See XCOPY /?